# How to prevent AdMob ads from getting placed at the bottom of the activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, admob

I'm showing ads randomly in a `RecyclerView` in my `MainActivity` using this code:

```
public static int count = 0;
public static int random = 0;

    if (count >= random) {
                    random = rand.nextInt(4);  // Reset the counter to random integer
                    count = 0;
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXX")
                            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXX")
                            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXX")
                            .build();
                    adView.loadAd(request);

                } else {
                    count++;
                }
```

Here's `xml` code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-***-****/*****"
        ads:adSize="320x80">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

I have a [FAB](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) in this activity and as clearly stated in the Google AdMob policy

> an ad should not be placed too near any action button or interactive
>   UI component of the app to prevent accidential clicks which can lead
>   to ban of the account.

So, in my case, the `FAB` sometimes overlaps the ad.

**What I want** to know is how to prevent the ad from getting placed at the bottom of the activity?

Is there any way of doing so from `xml` file or programmatically? Please let me know.

Comment: what is a FAB? also add data, are you trying to display a benner? if you can add the xml layout

Comment: @MichaelA Floating Action Button (FAB): https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

I'm trying to display a `Native Ads`: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6270315?hl=en See the edited question for `xml` code.